# Can't install Vim on Debian 9

Tags: debian, apt, vim

Sorry buy it's in spanish:

```
~# apt install vim
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete vim no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

E: El paquete «vim» no tiene un candidato para la instalación
```

Basically

```
The «vim» package does not have a candidate for installation
```

I've got Debian 9 installed and updated.

what source I have to add in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to get Vim installed?

**[@stephen-kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)** *this is my apt Policy (thanks!)*

```
~# LC_ALL=C apt policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `apt policy` output indicates you have 3 repositories configured:

- updates for the main repository
- security updates for the contrib repository
- security updates for the main repository

But you're missing the actual main repository itself (and also the contrib repository).

Add this line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib
```

These lines specify access to the full `main` and `contrib` repositories to `stretch`, not just to updates published after the release.

Then run `apt update` to update the repository contents lists, and finally try `apt install vim` again.

Comment: thanks! but edit the `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64` to this `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main amd64` and will work! thank you very much

Comment: Duh! That proves the sysadmin's golden rule: making configuration changes on Friday at around 4pm is never a good idea.